# mvvmcross Custom binding supressed by Linking optimisation to device

Tags: mvvmcross

In the Touch version of my app, I've defined a custom binding for the 'selected' property on a UIButton and use that to mimic the ToggleButton behaviour which is available in Android (to have the same UX in both platforms). This additional binding works perfectly fine in the simulator, but not when deploying to device. I've figured out already that this is again the famous linking optimisation problem as the binding does work when I change the Linker behaviour to 'don't link'.

Question, what do I need to include in the LinkerPleaseInclude to preserve my custom binding when deploying to device ? The UIButton in included there but only using the TouchUpInside event which therefore works fine on device - just my custom binding doesn't.

Thx

Comment: You need to include whatever it is your custom binding binds to using reflection... that may not sound very helpful - but it's as helpful as anyone can be without any code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.  Without any code example I can only suggest you search for UIButton in the LinkerPleaseInclude file and make sure you have something like:

```
var button = new UIButton();
button.Select += (s,a) => {}
```

Just need to reference the event so the compiler knows about it...